# How to get the status of a list of VM in Azure using Powershell Get-Azvm

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to get a list of Azure vm statuses (Allocated,Deallocated). I am able to get it one at a time for a single vm. But when i have a list of VM's or when using wildcard's it fails to get the vm status. Any tips

```
$ResGrp= "resvmtest"
$action="start"

 $vmList = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResGrp -Name *  -Status

       foreach($vm in ($vmList | Select-Object @batch)){
  Write-Host $vm.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus 
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you were trying to display the VMs in batches. Unless you have VMs in the thousands, that's not necessary. I also no longer see the `Statuses` property in Get-AzVM cmdlet. Just try this:

```
$vmList = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResGrp -Status
$vmList | Select-Object Name, PowerState, ProvisioningState # or any other properties you want to display
```

Either that or I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: I can't see PowerState, ProvisionState members of Get-AzVM

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour appears to have changed. Using the Status parameter now creates an object named Status and within that object.

One way to show the output:
select Name, @{n='New';e={($_.Statuses | where Code -eq 'PowerState/running').DisplayStatus}}

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :

```
Get-AzVm -ResourceGroupName <rg name> -Status | Select-Object Name, PowerState
```